# Abstract class over Interfaces in ADO.Net Environment

Tags: c#, vb.net, ado.net

I am developing a web app but is not satisfied with is architecture that I am following. The architecture is plain old conventional 3 tier architecture. 
What i want is follow some design pattern or architecture that will be help me in decoupling my code. 
I have idea about MVC and MVP architectures for Web App but i need different from that. I want to use OOPS concepts using abstract classes and interfaces, polymorphism etc in my app but not MVC and MVP. I dont know why?

I havent tried any ado.net application earlier via abstract class or interfaces, so i need your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find that much of what you're doing is already using interfaces (whether abstract classes or actual interfaces) and other oop design principles. Take a closer look at what you are doing and try to understand the underlying concepts that you are working with. Don't try to design for design's sake - patterns and principles are there to help solve problems, not to be an end unto themselves.

For learning more about design patterns I would simply start with [Wikipedia's article on Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science)) which gives a good overview as well as links for more details on specific patterns. Just remember that design patterns are a way to solve a common problem - they shouldn't be forced into an application.

Comment: thanks ryan, but what if you were in my place. What you will opt any existing architecture. I havent that much idea about the Design Patterns. Any good site or link. That would be a great help

Comment: +1 for the link to design patterns. There are quite a few and learning to use them properly can be a difficult journey.

Comment: @Amit, patterns are created based on grouping functions among other things. If you perform `funcA()`, `funcB()`, `funcC()` in different classes then design the pattern so that those functions are grouped into a base class (abstract or interface).

Answer (score 0):

I do not think anyone would be able to give you an accurate answer unless he knows about the kind of application you are developing.

I would say read about the design patterns available and then decide which pattern suites your application.

Comment: My application is pretty simple of Issue Tracking System. There is no such vast business algorithms simple CRUD operation. But i want design that will help me in updating my project at regular intervals as others do. For example trac [issue trackng system], is what i am developing on my own using ASP.Net with Sql Server 2008

Comment: +1 Thanks for point me out the missing thing. This will help others too, what i want to achieve.